# string matching behave incorrectly in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, pattern-matching

I have a problem using Google App Script for spreadsheet.

I have a function to search email subject to match against a spreadsheet column.

The subject in question is "New Shipment 20160504-S-00020 from DONG GUAN SHI CN", and matched against a cell value "DONG GUAN".

my code snippet:

```
thisOffice = range.offset(i, 0).getValue(); // get the value of "DONG GUAN" defined in the spreadsheet

if(thisOffice != ""){
  result = subject.indexOf(thisOffice);

  if (result > 0){
```

......

the program result a -1, which is not matched. This is strange, I tried to match this subject against other patterns like "Shipment" and "DONG", the result is positive. Only the function cannot find "DONG GUAN" within.

If the subject is "New Shipment 20160505-S-00007 from DONGGUAN CITY CN", it can match against "DONGGUAN CITY".

It seems it only cannot match against the word "DONG GUAN".

Comment: show us proof (logger.log) that your range has that string (hint: it doesnt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string may not be correct (contain extra spaces or misspelled), this test gives 35:

```
  function TestMatch() {

      var thisOffice = 'DONG GUAN';
      var subject = "New Shipment 20160504-S-00020 from DONG GUAN SHI CN";

      Logger.log(subject.indexOf(thisOffice));


  }
```

Try catching what value that was returned `Logger.log(thisOffice);` and `Logger.log(subject);`

Comment: Thanks, Max. I found the problem. In short, the subject displayed in Gmail has spaces removed and so is different than the real subject as seen in the script. In my case, the real subject is ....DONG(2 spaces here)GUAN....